# Match a domain and any subdomains

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a regex that will match a domain e.g nytimes.com in Elasticsearch to any of its subdomains such as cooking.nytimes.com, cn.nytimes.com, 9foo.nytimes.com, etc but not match fakenytimes.com. However it should also match regular nytimes.com

I tried using different variations of `([a-z].?)nytimes.com` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did you try `[^.]+\.nytimes\.com`? Note the backslash might need doubling. BTW, I understand you need it in Elasticsearch, so I removed Python references.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that it also needs to match regular nytimes.com

Comment: Ok, then `([^.]+\.)?nytimes\.com`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([^.]+\.)?nytimes\.com
```

It matches a full string (in ElasticSearch, the patterns are automatically anchored) that matches

- `([^.]+\.)?` - an optional sequence of any one or more chars other than `.` and then a `.` char
- `nytimes\.com` - a `nytimes.com` string.